# Update property for Realm entry

Tags: c#, .net, xamarin, xamarin.ios, realm

I using Realm database at my Xamarin project

I have realm object with this model

```
public class UserModel: RealmObject
{
    public string Id { get; set;}
    public string Email { get; set; }
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public byte[] UserAvatar { get; set; }
    public string ApiKey { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Surname { get; set; }
    public string Birthday { get; set; }
    public int Country_id { get; set; }
    public bool IsAuthorized { get; set; }
    public string Base64Avatar { get; set; }
    public string Telephone { get; set; }
}
```

I need to update `Name` property.

How I try to do this

```
var realm = Realm.GetInstance();
var user_check = realm.All<UserModel>().First(); 
user_check.Name = "Test"
```

and get this error

[image]

How I can fix this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding/Updating/Deleting to Realm object must be done inside a transaction, easiest way is to wrap it in `Write` method.

```
realm.Write(() => 
{
    user_check.Name = "Test";
});
```

For more info, check the [Rleam Write docs](https://realm.io/docs/dotnet/latest/#writes)